# Images align in columns

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to align several images horizontally and vertically inside a WordPress gallery. I want to have a grid of 3 images in a row, each aligned in the middle.

Here is the structure:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <dl>
        <dt><img src="#" /></dt>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt><img src="#" /></dt>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt><img src="#" /></dt>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt><img src="#" /></dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```

And what I have so far in CSS:

```
.gallery {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

dl {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The centering works well so far. But it makes ans many columns as there are images. What I want is a new row after every third image.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1008ozLk/) of what I have done so far.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` and add `width: 33%` instead:

```css
.gallery {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
dl {
  display: inline-block;/*add display inline block*/
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 33%;/*set width to 33%*/
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <dl> <dt><img src="http://placehold.it/400x100" /></dt>

  </dl>
  <dl> <dt><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" /></dt>

  </dl>
  <dl> <dt><img src="http://placehold.it/350x180" /></dt>

  </dl>
  <dl> <dt><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" /></dt>

  </dl>
</div>
```